# Reset all changes after last commit in git

Tags: git, git-commit, git-reset, git-revert

How can I undo *every* change made to my directory after the last commit, including deleting added files, resetting modified files, and adding back deleted files?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Revert to previous Git commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/revert-to-previous-git-commit)

Comment: @nawfal may be a duplicate, but 'reset all changes after last commit' matches more searching criteria(words searched in google) than corresponding 'how to revert git repository'. At least for people like me who don't have English as their mother tongue :d

Answer (score 762, accepted):

**First, reset any changes**

This will undo any changes you've made to tracked files and restore deleted files:

```
git reset HEAD --hard
```

**Second, remove new files**

This will delete any new files that were added since the last commit:

```
git clean -fd
```

Files that are not tracked due to `.gitignore` are preserved; they will not be removed

*Warning*:  using `-x` instead of `-fd` *would* delete ignored files.  You probably don't want to do this.

Comment: @Adam: You may sometimes want the `-x` option to `git clean` as well, which directs it to remove ignored files as well.

Comment: If you want to keep files that are not tracked due to .gitignore, be careful with the `git clean -fd` command.

Comment: @Levinaris: It is the other way around `git clean -fd` will not delete ignored files. `-x` will.

Comment: @RobertSiemer Actually, it can! If you have any folders composed entirely of ignored files it will remove those folders thus deleting ignored files.  Consider a .gitignore file like the one here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25554504/456645.  In this example, assume some folders have no PHP files.  `git clean -fd` will delete those folders and untracked files.  Tested with git version 1.9.1

Comment: @Levinaris: useful info! – Sounds like a bug in git, no?

Comment: @RobertSiemer I read this reply after I lost my ignored files

Comment: Tried the above command and my entire hard disk contents got deleted. Im unable to restore it anymore. Is there any ways to restore it back?

Comment: @Learner: Only from backups, but that is orthogonal to git.

Comment: bad day...,my entire projects  got deleted

Comment: but why the second 'clean out' needed at all?

Comment: I'm not upvoting this answer because it is on 444 and its look cool.

Comment: And I was shouting for 666.

Comment: @Learner  am about to run the above commands, was that a joke about it deleting the entire disk contents ?

Answer (score 107):

> How can I undo **every change** made to my directory after the last commit, including deleting added files, resetting modified files, and adding back deleted files?

1. You can undo changes to *tracked* files with:

   ```
   git reset HEAD --hard
   ```
2. You can remove *untracked* files with:

   ```
   git clean -f
   ```
3. You can remove *untracked* files and directories with:

   ```
   git clean -fd
   ```

   but **you can't undo change to untracked files**.
4. You can remove *ignored and untracked* files and directories

   ```
   git clean -fdx
   ```

   but **you can't undo change to ignored files**.

You can also set `clean.requireForce` to `false`:

```
git config --global --add clean.requireForce false
```

to avoid using `-f` (`--force`) when you use `git clean`.

Comment: Awesome, just what I needed. Thanks for the comparison of all the relevant commands!

Comment: `git reset HEAD --hard` seemed to be enough for me to undo changes to the latest commit.

Answer (score -13):

There are two commands which will work in this situation,

root>git reset --hard HEAD~1

root>git push -f

For more git commands refer this [page](https://medium.com/@arcodershub/git-commands-for-windows-eb5ed75bda3f?sk=9dfce31790b5f933be2d9210f8b47a15)

Comment: `git push -f` is not related to the question and, in this scenario, is dangerous

Comment: This will remove the last commit from the remote repository, instead of dropping all changes *since* the last commit.

Comment: Please delete this answer, it does the opposite of what the OP asked, and thus unsafe. Deleting this answer will also restore your lost rep.

Comment: this will delete all including the last commit too..