# how to remove changes since last git commit

Tags: git, revert

This is probably a simple (but irritating) question.  How do you remove all changes remove changes since last commit?  I botched a patch, and I want to go back to how things were at my last commit.

I have tried:

```
git reset --hard master
```

and

```
git checkout master
```

but neither rid my folders of the files hat I have added / changed (they are still listed as untracked files.)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Reset all changes after last commit in git](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4630312/1199226)

Answer (score 5):

Untracked files are just that, untracked.  Git doesn't know or care about them.  `git reset --hard` will only revert tracked files to the state they were in at the most recent (or named) commit.

You can use `git clean` to remove untracked files and directories from your working tree.  Be careful you don't accidentally delete any hard work!

The "silver bullet" that will restore a repository back to the state it was at as of the most recent commit, *as if you had just cloned it* (**this will even remove all user files that are "ignored" by the repository!**) would be this:  `git reset --hard && git clean -fdx`.  (If you omit the `x` flag then it will only remove untracked files that are not ignored, which might include build products, for example.)

Comment: is there a required operator?  git actually refused to do it (and told me so in no uncertain terms)  it says it needs -i -n or -f

Comment: @Hoytman I'd suggest reading the manpage.  By default, it will refuse to operate unless you specify the `-f` argument.  You can instead specify the `-n` argument to see what it *would* do if you supplied `-f`, without actually doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could just comment on this, but check this out:
[How to undo last commit(s) in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-to-undo-the-last-git-commit)

and here:
http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset

Answer (score 0):

A little late to this one, but seeing that on 2017/09/26 this was still indexed as third using the google search engine here is my response. I found what worked for me via this stack exchange discussion: [git undo all uncommitted or unsaved changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14075581/git-undo-all-uncommitted-or-unsaved-changes)

Basically **if you have not used git add** yet then use:

```
git checkout .
```

To **unstage files staged with git add** use:

```
git reset
```