# What does !*/ mean in .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

With git version 1.7.1, I'm trying to exclude all files except .php files.

The working solution I found relies on the command `!*/`

```
# Ignore Everything
*

# Except these files
!.gitignore
!*/
!*.php
```

Without the `!*/`, it will only include the `*.php` files in the root directory. What is `!*/` doing that allows this to work?

Comment: `!` Don't ignore `*` everything in this directory `/` that ends with a slash. Aka don't ignore subdirectories.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation of gitignore](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

> An optional prefix "!" which negates the pattern; any matching file
>   excluded by a previous pattern will become included again. It is not
>   possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is
>   excluded. Git doesn’t list excluded directories for performance
>   reasons, so any patterns on contained files have no effect, no matter
>   where they are defined. Put a backslash ("\") in front of the first
>   "!" for patterns that begin with a literal "!", for example,
>   "!important!.txt".

Comment: Earlier, I missed the critical part of this paragraph... "It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded."  Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

Here's my line of thinking:

The ignore statement `*` will ignore everything by default, **including the root directory and all of its contents.**

So at this point, **all files and folders in the root directory are ignored.**

The `!*.php` command will re-include all the `*.php` files in the root path, but the folders are still being ignored (because they don't end in `.php`) - and therefore, they're not negated from the gitignore yet.

So the `!*/` command re-includes all the directories (and subsequent sub-directories) so that they can be examined for `*.php` files. Example: `folder1/` matches the negation statement `!*/` because it contains the `/` at the end and the folder name fits in the wildcard operator `*`

Comment: That totally makes sense to me, except: wouldn't the `!*/` line need to come _before_ the `*.php` line, so git can see the directories in which to search for php files? Or does order not have any effect in `.gitignore`?

Comment: @JacobFord Correct - the docs specify a previous pattern, and `.gitignore` files are read top-to-bottom (otherwise, how would a previous pattern be determined?) The folders would not be known to `!*.php` if it came before `!*/`. This just wasn't the focus of the question at hand. You can think of the `.gitignore` file like a funnel.

Comment: My bad! It seemed your answer was implying that `!*.php` would come before `!*/`, but now I see you were just explaining it in that order.