# gitignore - is there any difference between !/**/ and !*/

Tags: git, gitignore

I was going through the answers of [How do I add files without dots in them (all extension-less files) to the gitignore file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19023550/1772898)

One answer is:

```
*
!/**/
!*.*
```

and the other answer is:

```
*
!*/
!*.*
```

So, is there any difference between `!/**/` and `!*/` or are they similar.

Comment: Something that explains what !*/ is :https://stackoverflow.com/q/25554504/6309111

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I wrote [the original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19023985/6309) (in 2013), I believe my intent was to anchor the exclusion at the top folder '`/`' (where the `.gitignore` is), with the [special format](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format):

> A trailing "`/**`" matches everything inside. For example, "`abc/**`" matches all files inside directory "`abc`", relative to the location of the `.gitignore` file, with infinite depth.

Meaning I want to exclude all *folders* (`**/`) starting from the top (`/`: inside top folder).

That is a more complex way to write `*/` with:

- '`*`': match anything (except '`/`') at any depth
- '`/`': match only folders (which ends with '`/`')

In both instances, the idea remains:

- ignore everything
- except folders
- *then* except dot files

Comment: @blueray Sure, there is no rush though.