# .gitignore to ignore everything aside from files with certain extensions in nested subdirectories associated with some top level subdirectories

Tags: git, gitignore

I would like for git to ignore all files except those with a few different extensions buried somewhere within a specific set of subdirectories.

For examples, say I have a directory with the following sub-directories:

```
subdir1
subdir2
subdir3
subdir4
subdir5
...
```

Each subdirectory contains an arbitrary number of nested sub-directories. Files with extension `.txt` or `.pdf` may be present in some of those nested sub-directories. I would like to have the repo track only the `.txt` and `.pdf` files somewhere within `subdir2` and `subdir3` and no other files.

Please explain why your solution works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ignore **ALL** files expect all `.pdf` and `.txt` files in the directory `subdir2/` and `subdir3/`, add following to `gitignore`:

```
# Ignore everything
*
!*/

# But not these files
!.gitignore
!subdir2/**/*.pdf
!subdir2/**/*.txt
!subdir3/**/*.pdf
!subdir3/**/*.txt
```

`subdir/**` matches *all files* and *directories* in any `subdir/` directory and all of its subdirectories. The `!` negates the pattern where follows. And so you can ignore all **except** the `.pdf` and `.txt` files in the wished directories.

The folder-structure is as follow:

```
|-- folder
    |-- .git
    |-- .gitignore
    |-- subdir1/
        |-- <folder content>
    |-- subdir2/
        |-- <folder content>
    |-- subdir3/
        |-- <folder content>
    |-- subdir4/
        |-- <folder content>
    |-- subdir5/
        |-- <folder content>
```

Comment: Don't I need to prefix each line with ```!``` if I want to include these?  Also, don't I need something to ignore everything except the relevant files?

Comment: The `!` is when you have add `/subdir2/*` in gitignore (ignore all files inside `subdir2`), but you want an exception and do not want to ignore the folder `/subdir2/folder`, so you must write `!/subdir2/folder` and exclude this folder from gitignore. But in your example this is not necessary, **except** you have in your gitignore-file ignore as example *subdir2* (`subdir2/*`), then you need the `!`.

Comment: The proposed answer does not give the correct result.  Perhaps my question was unclear.  I wish to include only the pdf and tex files anywhere under ```subdir2``` and ```subdir3```  and no other files.

Comment: You want to include the `.pdf` and the `.txt` to gitignore, si that git all these files ignore? Or want you**only** the files with the ending of `.pdf` and `.txt` **not** ignored? For me thr question is still not clear... In my answer above it is explain, that **all** files with ending of `.pdf` and `.txt` where ignored by gitignore.

Comment: Modified question in response to your comment.

Comment: There is a continued miscommunication.  I don't want to ignore the ```.pdf``` and ```.txt``` files.  I wish to track _only_  ```.pdf``` and ```.txt``` files under source control.

Comment: Very unclear how you formulated your question. Then put the optional prefix in front of it: `!subdir2/**/*.pdf` and ignore all other files with simple `*` at the top of the `.gitignore`-file. Look at my answer...

Comment: Yes.  I think that ```!.gitignore``` is needed to include the ```.gitignore``` file.  Beyond that, it doesn't seem to find any of the ```.txt``` and ```.pdf``` files to track ...

Comment: Look and say if it works, I edited the answer again

Comment: That works!  Can you please explain why ```!*/``` is needed and how that is different from ```!/*```?

Comment: Look at this stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25554504/what-does-mean-in-gitignore)