# How to discard changes in Git?

Tags: git, github

1. I forked other repository to my own account.
2. I cloned this **forked** repository to my computer.
3. Now i have 2 changed files, ready to commit them (I do not know why). To update (git rebase) my cloned forked repository from origin, I need to have working directory clean. But i haven't, because of this. The only thing come to my mind is to make working directory clean by **DISCARD** those changes, and then i get my purpose. How to do this? Is there a way to fix this issue?

Otherwise, I am not able to rebase my local repository.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reset all changes after last commit in git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630312/reset-all-changes-after-last-commit-in-git)

Answer (score 2):

Discard: [`git reset --hard`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) followed by `git clean -d -x -f`, as mentioned in "[How do I clear my local working directory in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/675797/6309)".
But make sure you didn't want to get back those current modifications: [they wouldn't be easy to restore (for the ones added to the index)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1109433/6309).

But if you want a safer option: [`git stash`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash).
That would save any current modification in the stash, leaving your working tree clean.

Comment: It doesn't work. When i tap `git reset --hard` and then `git rebase upstream/master` i get `Cannot rebase: You have unstaged changes.
Please commit or stash them.`

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk can you try `git config core.autocrlf false` first? And then `git reset --hard`.

Comment: The same report as before

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk do you have `.gitattributes` files anywhere, with `core.oel` directives in them?

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk it would explain why the reset --hard doesn't get rid of eol which could have been the "unstaged changes" you see.

Comment: the changes appear when i fork the cdnjs/cdnjs repo from Github. This is described [here](https://github.com/cdnjs/cdnjs/issues/3650). I have changed files, although i changed nothing.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk and `git config core.autocrlf` (when executed from within your local clone) does return false?

Answer (score 0):

There are also two other ways, such as:

`git checkout .` and `git restore .`

(the latter is preferred, according to https://www.golinuxcloud.com/git-discard-changes/)

These commands discard changes in all files in that directory.